# How to re-queue message with updated information while working with Azure Service Bus Queue Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues, retrypolicy

While working with Azure Service Bus Queue function, we know that whenever there is an exception, azure function will perform a default retry policy (max count = 10), what we would like to do is to have our message with a property called **retryCount**, so when exception generates, we would increase the **retryCount += 1**, and also add the current exception to our message, then next time while function performs the retry, **we could know this is the xth time that it comes in along with x records of exceptions**. We know that the **Message** object had a read-only property called **deliveryCount**, however, we cannot bind our addition information or figure out *what would be the reason of last failed delivery* from the **Message** object.

However, after we tried to implement our idea, we found that **whenever the function performs the retry, it always reload the initial message from the queue**, not with our updated message. Is there any way to let it retry with updated message without force to re-send the updated back to the current queue?

In addition, how could we customize the current retry logic, for example, decrease the max retry count from 10 to 1 and use Polly to handle some scenario inside the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need a custom `retryCount` as the message already contains a system property called `DeliveryCount` that tracks the number of delivery (read processing) attempts. If you need to store some additional metadata between the retries, you would need to [abandon](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus--abandon-with-reason) your message. With Functions v2, to abandon a message you will need to use the message receiver used to receive the message.

```
public static async Task ProcessMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue")] string message,
int deliveryCount,
MessageReceiver messageReceiver,
string lockToken)
{
  //
  await messageReceiver.AbandonAsync(lockToken, 
            new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Reason", "Blah" });
}
```

Note that to ensure Azure Functions continues to process the message you will need to throw an exception. Otherwise, Functions by default assumes the message was processed successfully and will attempt to complete the message.

Comment: thank you for sharing that! Does this abadon mean drop and re-create the message and perform another retry? By that I mean, would my instance of function be a new one or still the existed one?

Comment: It's not complete and replace with a clone. Abandon means abandon. Just what you asked for.

Comment: I've read through the article and tried this implementation today, but **how could I retrieve my custom property**, for example in this case the **Reason** from my message? Where is this dictionary stored? I am wondering if this is within MessageReceiver, but when I debug it I couldn't find there is a property or dictionary related to the "Reason"...Could you please guide me further on this?

Comment: Reason would be a custom property under `message.UserProperties` dictionary.

Comment: Thank you and I will try that! Just a quick question, should I put the _AbadonAsync_ in try block or catch block? Right now I am putting this in catch block as I would like to handle exception as reason in metadata retries, like ```try { ... } catch  (Exception ex) { await messageReceiver.AbadonAsync(lockToken, new Dictionary<string, object> {{ "Exception", ex.Message }}; throw ex```, am I doing correct?

Comment: hello I might have a stuck point...looks like only string would work with the value in Dictionary<string, object> although the value type here is **object**, when I tried to save a list of items as object, I am not able to retrieve my value when next time the message passed in...

Comment: Headers only accept primitive types. If you need a list, you will need to serialize.

Comment: Thank you! Yes this is what I am currently doing by serializing my list into string, just had a concern by doing that, what would happen if the message content grows larger to exceed service bus function message limit (2MB maybe)

Comment: Just curious that I've found another example about using **MessageSender.ScheduleMessageAsync** and **MessageReceiver.CompleteAsync(lockToken)** to resend the message back to the queue, what would be the difference of using **Abadon** vs **Schedule & Complete** here? Is it because the latter one will create a new lockToken in next-try?

Comment: @KevDing, there are multiple ways to skin a cat. You know better which one works for you. Scheduling is used for future messages where Abandon is more suited with "give up and retry immediately".